# How can I change the location.hash of a target window, without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, window.open

I'm currently using one page to spawn a new window, with a timed playback URLs in it. Many of the pages it's loading respond to hash navigation. I'm doing this like:

```
window.open(url,"playback");
```

As we play through the URLs, we should see the page respond accordingly. The problem I've run into however, is that the window.open() call actually reloads the page when the hash is changed.

For instance, loading "**pageA.htm**", then "**pageB.htm#tab2**" works flawlessly. The issue however is that when I try to go from "**pageB.htm#tab2**" to "**pageB.htm#tab3**"; the page reloads (responding properly to hash) completely instead of just firing "onhashchange" as I'd expect.

Is there an alternative to window.open() that I should call for hash-only changes, that will prevent full page reload?

Edit: The final solution looks something like this:

```
playbackWindow = window.open(url,"playback");
```

Then when we want to change the hash:

```
playbackWindow.location.href = "poundIt";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `window.open` to change the hash without reloading the page. Simply change the value of `window.location.hash` instead.

Comment: Pretty close, but we run into cross domain issues trying to access window.location.hash on the new window.

Comment: Aha, so from page X you open page Y, and then want to change the hash on page Y from page X? :- ) Well, then I suggest using `window.postMessage` to communicate between the two pages, as demonstrated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage. That way you could just send an event from page X and tell page Y to update its own hash.

Comment: At this point I just pushed it with a big `if xdomain` clause that falls back to window.open with a target. Ideally page Y is ignorant that it's being puppeteered from page X, and requires no special fiddling for being remote controlled. Thanks for point me at using the location object / window ref instead of blindly asking the browser to find the right one by name :)

Comment: Accepting this answer as it works in any non-cross-domain scenario, which are their own set of headaches unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.hash = "This";
```

should do the trick.